# ¿Cómo generar a partir de una imagen grande las distintas densidades y almacenarlas en las carpetas Drawable en android?

Tags: android

Estoy creando una aplicación *móvil* , desarrollada en **Android** , si bien en la carpeta **Drawable** se almacena las las imágenes , y en las demás **Drawables** de densidad se almacenan las mismas imágenes en distintos tamaños , se podrá generar a partir de la misma imagen de gran tamaño las distintas densidades ,  tal como la hay para los iconos .

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: no es error de codigos amigo , es simplemente para facilitarme la cosas , si bien las densidades mayores son hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi , quiero apartir de una imagen grande generas esas imagenes de menor densidad , para ahorrar tiempo y facilitar las cosas de no usar un editor externo.

Comment: Tienes una imagen y deseas generar las 5 imágenes (hdpi,mdip, etc) para android ?

Comment: si exactamente deseo eso , tengo entendido que hay para los iconos de la app

Comment: Decirme si me equivoco, pero no creo que se pueda, yo las hacía a mano :s

Answer (score 2):

Hay un plugin en Android Studio que se llama **Android Drawable Importer** si lo instalas al hacer click derecho en la carpeta de tu proyecto > new > Batch Drawable Import, ahí puedes elegir una imagen, de acuerdo a su resolución poner si es ldpi, mdpi, etc. y seleccionar las densidades que deseas generar, entonces automáticamente genera la imagen en el resto de las densidades.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas opciones son:

Simple nine-patch generator:  [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example)

- soporta xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi
- Se trata de una plataforma online.

ImageMagick II: [link](https://noroute2host.com/imagemagick-android.html)

- soporta xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi
- se trata de un script que se ejecuta por consola.

9-Patch-Resizer: [link](https://github.com/redwarp/9-patch-resizer)

- Soporta , xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi
- Se trata de un software de escritorio algo desactualizado.
  (su última actualización fue en el 2015)

Answer (score -1):

Buenas.

Desde mi experiencia, las relaciones para las imágenes se deben manejar en porcentajes.

Primero haz la imagen lo mas grande que puedas, en resoluciones de 1920x1080 (obviamente depende de la relación de aspecto) para imágenes, si pueden ser vectoriales, es mejor. Esto es para poder tener la mejor calidad en los recursos, estos nunca deben ser menores. Los originales se mantienen así, no se incluyen en la aplicación sino que se exportan como copias de menor tamaño y esas copias se incluyen como assets o drawables.

Luego exporta tus imágenes al tamaño estándar que es tamaño de pantalla `normal` con la densidad media `mdpi`

Entonces partiendo de esa densidad y tamaño debes usar los tamaños de imagen proporcionales con las medidas en porcentajes relativos como lo indica la [documentación oficial de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=es):

- 36 x 36 (0,75x o 75%) para densidad baja `ldpi`
- 48 x 48 (referencia de 1,0X o 100%) para densidad media `mdpi`
- 72 x 72 (1,5x o 150%) para densidad alta `hdpi`
- 96 x 96 (2,0x o 200%) para densidad extraalta `xhdpi`
- 144 x 144 (3,0x o 300%) para densidad extra extraalta `xxhdpi`

Esto quiere decir que si tienes una imagen de 48x48 y la quieres para densidades de HDPI debes exportar tu original al 150% de la densidad normal. Para hacer estas conversiones puedes usar Photoshop, [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) o algún convertidor en linea como en [este Link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html).

Este [blog en ingles](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/density-converter/) explica este proceso de una forma similar.

Comment: si esa parte la tengo clara , pero asi como los iconos de una app se pueden generar todas a partir de una sola imagen , quiero saber si puedo hacer lo mismo con los drawables.

Comment: Puedes usar características de photoshop como en este post [[LINK](http://www.digitalartsonline.co.uk/tutorials/photoshop/how-resize-multiple-images-in-photoshop/)] o también puedes hacerlo con herramientas de bash como en linux [[LINK](http://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/)] entonces usas los porcentajes :P